# Acceder a la base de datos de Django desde un script ajeno a Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Cuando intento acceder a la base de datos que crea automáticamente Django desde el interprete, o desde un script que no ha creado Django por si mismo, recibo un error.

**Código** en el que intento importar el modelo *User* de la aplicacion llamada *app*:

```
from app.models import User
```

**Error** que imprime al intentar hacer esa operación:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Accede a la base directamente. Django crea tablas comunes y corrientes que puedes consultar con cualquier herramienta que pueda conectarse a tu base de datos. Lo que tu estás intentando hacer es usar el ORM de Django... y pues eso ya no sería _"ajeno a Django"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo pongo este fragmento de código al inicio del script:

```
import os
import django
import sys
sys.path.append('../../')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "imharvol.settings")
django.setup()
```

Pero recuerda cambiar el directorio en `sys.path.append('../../')` y poner el directorio base de tu proyecto (donde esta el manage.py). Tambien tendras que cambiar el *imharvol* `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "imharvol.settings")` por el nombre del directorio donde este tu archivo *settings.py*, en este caso, el proyecto se llamaba *imharvol*, y por defecto los settings están en un directorio llamado igual que el nombre de tu proyecto.

Después de esto ya puedes importar tu modelo User.

```
from app.models import User
```